# How can my input element receive onclick events when it is set to disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, events, input

I need to have an onclick/hover event on an input tag which is disabled.
Is there another way but to wrap it in another tag and give that tag the events?

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="cant_choose('event')" disabled="disabled" value="2" name="enroll_to[event][]">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could *simulate* it being disabled with JavaScript and CSS.

That is, blur all focus it receives, and add a class with something like so.

```
input.disabled {
    background: #d4d0c8;
    color: #888;
    cursor: default;
}
```

### Update

See it in comparison with the normal and browser disabled input box on [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/ixutu3/edit).

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that browser will send these faux-disabled form elements when the form is submitted.  That is not the case for truly-disabled form elements.

Comment: @Peter On form submit you could really set `disabled` on them.

Comment: You might also want to add a placeholder and readonly attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the input field inside a container and bind the click event on it.

```
<div id='input-container'>
    <input id='myText' disabled />
</div>

<script>
    $('#input-container').click(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M2EYH/

If you have multiple disabled fields, and don't want to make an unique ID for each container, you can give the containers a class name instead of an ID.

Comment: Well, it does work in Chrome and IE but doesn't work in Firefox and Opera. Do you have any idea how to make it work in all browsers?