# why the second event is not started?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me figure out why the second event is not started ([full code](http://jsfiddle.net/7tLnq/1/))

```
<input type="submit" value="disabled:false" />

$(function(){
    $('input:submit').bind({
       mouseover : function(){
            $('input:submit').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(this).val('disabled:' + $(this).attr('disabled'));
            });
        },
        mouseout : function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(this).val('disabled:' + $(this).attr('disabled'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what second event are you talking about?

Comment: love it...ask a question get a question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery event on a disabled input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100319/jquery-event-on-a-disabled-input), also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819404/how-can-my-input-element-receive-onclick-events-when-it-is-set-to-disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're disabling the control in your `mouseover` handler, so input messages are suppressed and `mouseout` never fires.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve by disabling all submit buttons when the mouse pointer lies over one of them...

Comment: I'd like to undersand why input messages are suppressed and mouseout never fires

Comment: @Algorithm - mouse events aren't fired from `disabled` elements, that's just part of how the DOM works.

Answer (score 1):

`mouseout` event's won't fire for `disabled` elements.